# Can I subscribe my Python script, running on Android, to get Broadcast Events?

Tags: android, python

Short intro: I have an Android phone and a campus WiFi network, and to be logged in I need to enter the same login and password each time I get connected to it.
So I've decidet to write small script, which would do thatt automaticaly.

But, as I understood, I have to subscribe to NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION event, so the question is - is there any way to do it in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a definite answer, but you might want to look in these places for inspiration:

- [Python for Android](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [Pyjnius](http://pyjnius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)
- [Pygame Subset for Android](http://pygame.renpy.org/)

Comment: Thank you! I think I can deal with the problem, combinig Pyjnius and Py4A